# How to configure a web-app correctly, so that axis2 finds required modules?

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

I currently face the problem that I have a web application including an axis 2 web service client, which should use rampart for the security header. Therefore, I adapted the axis2.xml file, included all libraries and the rampart module in the web-app. Putting axis2.xml in the classpath (eg. /WEB-INF/classes/axis2.xml) works fine. But what about the module repository? I tried different locations (WEB-INF/classes/modules, WEB-INF/modules) but it simply does not work. Everytime I try to create the ConfigurationContext for the client, I get an exception that the module rampart couldn't be found.

Here is how I create the context (nothing special...)

```
ConfigurationContext ctx = ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromURIs(axis2Location, moduleLocation);
```

and thats the exception I receive:

```
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The system is attempting to engage a module that is not available: rampart
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.URLBasedAxisConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(URLBasedAxisConfigurator.java:78)
    at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:68)
    at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromURIs(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:194)
    at com.test.webclient.Environment.create(Environment.java:88)
    ... 32 more
```

So i am curious - **how should someone specify the modules location, when using an axis2 client inside a web-application?** Any help is appreciated :).

Edit: Some more information from my side:

-> AS used is JBoss 5.1GA
-> Axis2 version is 1.4.1
-> Axis2 jar(s) are delivered with my application in WEB-INF/lib, they do not exist anywhere else on the Appserver (eg. JBOSS_HOME/lib).

Also I would like to point out, that only the module is not found. If I do not provide a customzed axis2.xml (where the module is defined), the client works just fine.

Comment: Hi! Did you solve it? I have same problem....9 years after

Answer (score 0):

Where do you have the axis classes themselves? For example, URLBasedAxisConfigurator.

You don't say which App Server you're running in, but some app servers have a hierachy of classloaders, and not all loading code uses the same classloaders.

So for example if Axis were coming from a class loaders defined by the app server itself rather than your application then your application's classes would not be visible to Axis. Hence you would need to the module out in some app server-defined directory, or use app server-specific mechanisms to tell it where to look.

Even more confusing, you can have a copy of Axis delivered with your app and one deliverd with the app server, and you may not  be using the one you think you are.

Using your JVM's verbose classloader option (which will produce a **lot** of information) you may  be able to see the search path that is being tried in looking for the module and hence get a clue about where to put it.

Comment: Some more information from my side:

AS used is JBoss 5.1GA. Axis2 version is 1.4.1. Axis2 jar(s) are delivered with my application in WEB-INF/lib, they do not exist anywhere else on the Appserver (eg. JBOSS_HOME/lib).

Also I would like to point out, that only the module is not found. If I do not provide a customzed axis2.xml (where the module is defined), the client works just fine. (Included this information also in my problem description :)).